# createShareIntent with Picasso library

Tags: java, android

I open images fullscreen from a productDetails activity. This new fullScreeActivity is working fine in the first try. Problem is happening when I press android native back button to return to productDetails and so try to open fullScreeActivity with the same image (just as if I´d like to see the image full again). The app crashes.

When I remove createShareIntent() and Picasso codes it works fine. So I suppose this is the cause of the problem. Is there a better way of doing this?

productDetails.java

```
ImageView arquivo;
private static final String TAG_ARQUIVO = "arquivo";
String imagem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image_available)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image_available)
.cacheInMemory(true)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
.displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

arquivo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arquivo);

Intent i = getIntent();
imagem = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ARQUIVO);

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(imagem, arquivo, defaultOptions);

arquivo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent iFullImg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreenActivity.class);
        iFullImg.putExtra(TAG_ARQUIVO, imagem);
        startActivity(iFullImg);

    }
});
}
```

fullScreenActivity.java

```
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private static final String TAG_ARQUIVO = "arquivo";
String path;
File file;

ImageView fullImg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image_available)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image_available)
.cacheInMemory(true)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
.displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

fullImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);


Intent i = getIntent();
path = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ARQUIVO);

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(path, fullImg, defaultOptions);

mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(fullImg);


Picasso.with(this).load(path).into(fullImg, new Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        createShareIntent();
    }
});

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.full_screen, menu);

  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
  mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

  return true;
}

private void createShareIntent() {

Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(fullImg);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);


}

public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {

Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bmp = null;
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
   bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
} else {
   return null;
}

Uri bmpUri = null;
try {
    File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    out.close();
    bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  return bmpUri;
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.habitodigital.handy/com.habitodigital.handy.FullScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.habitodigital.handy.FullScreenActivity.createShareIntent(FullScreenActivity.java:99)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.habitodigital.handy.FullScreenActivity.access$0(FullScreenActivity.java:91)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.habitodigital.handy.FullScreenActivity$1.onSuccess(FullScreenActivity.java:74)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:514)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.habitodigital.handy.FullScreenActivity.onCreate(FullScreenActivity.java:66)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-31 05:22:01.395: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What does your logcat say about the crash? It will show you the exception that will tell you precisely which line of code is causing the problem and why.

Comment: Tanis.7x it just gives me NullPointerException. This is why I´m not finding what to do.

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: @madsongr Identifying that it gives you a `NullPointerException` is a great first step. It should also tell you on what line of which class that NPE occurred. From there, you should be able to set a break point and identify precisely which variable is null, then examine why it might be null.

Comment: I tried to use private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) to update the share intent with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some modifications and simplifications that I did, the NPE was solved.

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends Activity {

PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private static final String TAG_ARQUIVO = "arquivo";
String path;
File file;
Intent shareIntent;
ImageView fullImg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    fullImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    path = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ARQUIVO);

    Picasso.with(FullScreenActivity.this).load(path).into(fullImg);
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(fullImg);

    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(fullImg);

    shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.full_screen, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
    return true;
}

public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {

    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
       bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
       return null;
    }

    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the attention.